# Reset EF code-first database in LocalDB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, reset, localdb

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 RC with the LocalDB database that comes pre-configured with VS 2012 RC for some prototyping and testing of code-first database.

After a few cycles of changing my code-first database and running "update-database" I did a huge breaking change and automatic migration failed bad. I don't care about resolving this conflict since this is just prototyping, so losing data is fine.

How do I reset or delete the database? 
Reset must also reset the migration table, which seems to be hidden from Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: I found some articles on how to make __MigrationHistory table a non-system table, which in turn allowed me to delete all tables and migration history from within Server Explorer. Still, not a very quick way to reset so I am open to ideas here. Another point I came across was to NOT use AutomaticMigration, which I had. When enabled it is a pain to back out of a migration error, because there is no code to see what is going on.

Comment: You could recreate the database by setting the Initializer  `Database.SetInitializer(new AlwaysRecreateDatabase<DataContext>());`

Comment: Thanks, yes I was aware of that and I think I had success running that code in a console app just to clear everything out. Still looking for something that is a little easier for everyone on the team to do whenever the database needs to be reset, such as a SQL script to execute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drop the whole database in Visual Studio

1. Open SQL Server Object Explorer
2. Find the database you are working with Right click and select delete
3. Select the two check boxes (Delete backup and restore history, and Close existing connections) and click ok
4. Run program again and it should recreate the dabase

Comment: It's been a while since this question, but yes this is the approach I currently use as well to reset the DB. On a side note, I'm not sure when this changed, but in my recent projects the migration history table is apparently no longer a system-table.

Answer (score 1):

So far this is the best approach I have found.

1. Make __MigrationHistory a non-system table.
2. Execute SQL script to drop all tables.

To alter __MigrationHistory table, see [this article](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/27/code-first-migrations-making-__migrationhistory-not-a-system-table/) to handle both existing databases and new databases created with code-first.

The SQL script is as follows:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?";
```

I am using [Database .NET v4 Free](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ec14ae60-cc0a-4c8e-a8a3-81dec4730096) to run this SQL script, because my Visual Studio 11 RC copy won't let me run queries on LocalDB for some reason. Also, I need to run the script twice for it to drop all tables due to some foreign keys. I haven't bothered fixing this since it seems to work well enough as it is.